# Why is Yuki surprised by the Level E vampires?

Tags: vampire-knight

In "Vampire Knight"  ep. 3, entitled 'Fangs of Repentance', Yuki seems genuinely surprised by the Level E vampires she encounters in town. It's like she had no idea vampires could be that awful.

She never seems to want to believe that vampires are bad, and even tells Zero that she probably should start listening to him and accept that there really are some bad vampires out there, only **after** her attack.

Why does she seem so surprised by Level E Vamps? Her earliest memory is of Kaname killing a clearly monstrous vampire. She should know and accept how bad they can be right off the bat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's apart of Yuuki's denial that Vampires can be bad, don't forget her earliest memory if that of her idolized Kaname soaked in blood yet she doesn't fear him (at first). Also as a Guardian all the other Vampires she has met are in the Night Class and none of them are like the Level E she encounters.

We see later during the the first part of the series Yuuki trying to deny that the Vampires of the Night Class, particularly Kaname, and the Level E's are the same blood thirsty creatures but Kaname tries to make Yuuki understand they are the same by letting her see him drink Ruka's blood being fully aware Yuuki was peaking though the door. he did this knowing

> that if Yuuki is afraid of Vampires she wont want to return to being one

i also suspect that when Yuuki went into the Night Class Dorm during the day and almost had her blood taken by Aidou Kaname was well aware the moment Yuuki entered but also knew Aidou was awake. making sure to stop Aidou at the right moment